# d3 multi circle series data chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

How would this be adapted to superimpose a second set of circles?

```
  var data = [{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Facebook",
    "items": [{
      "value": 200
    }, {
      "value": 300
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Ebay",
    "items": [{
      "value": 1000
    }, {
      "value": 2000
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Foursquare",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    }]
  }]
```

with the option of adding other data sets - the goal to create a 2D pyramid of sorts with different coloured circles representing the different data sets -- with the largest dataset taking the base circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/0aqvx66j/4/

```
function circleMaker() {


    var counter = 0;
    series = 0


    var set = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "series" + series);

    set.selectAll("circle")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("circle")
      .attr("class", "series" + series)
      .attr("cy", 60)
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        if (i) {
          return (counter += Math.sqrt(data[i - 1].items[series].value) + Math.sqrt(data[i].items[series].value));
        } else {
          return counter;
        }
      })
      .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        var colorArray = ["#00ccff", "#fcdd0a"];
        return colorArray[series];
      })
      .attr("r", function(d) {
        return Math.sqrt(d.items[series].value);
      });

}
```

eventually maybe even flip between the different data sets to always place the largest circle as the background. So like this

[image]

Comment: Is the `second set of circles` the second value in the `items` array?

Comment: sure -- {
    "name": "Twitter",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    }

Comment: idea is -- what if we added a third set -- so then display 3 circles but --- take the largest circle as the base, then build it up like a 2D pyramid.

Comment: This is great information you should include in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of it is just organising the data before plotting it. Within each series give each item an index, and then sort by value. The index property will then tell us the initial position of each item in the series. The first item in each series will now be the biggest value. Use this to build an offset for each series, and sum all these offsets to make a scale for positioning.

Then make group elements for each series, positioning using the offset we calculated.

Within each group, draw the circle elements. Since we sorted them they'll be drawn biggest first. The .index property can be used to colour by their original place in the series.

http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/2/

```
var width = 600;
var height = 400;
var svg = d3.select('svg').attr("width", width).attr("height",height);


  var data = [{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Facebook",
    "items": [{
      "value": 200
    }, {
      "value": 300
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Ebay",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 1000
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Foursquare",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    },
    {
      "value": 4000
    }]
  }];


  // organise the data. 
  // Insert indices and sort items in each series
  // keep a running total of max circle size in each series
  // for later positioning
  var x = 0;
  var totalWidth = d3.sum (
    data.map (function (series) {
      series.items.forEach (function (item, i) {
            item.index = i;
      });
      series.items.sort (function (a, b) {
        return b.value - a.value;
      });
      var maxr = Math.sqrt(series.items[0].value);
      x += maxr;
      series.xcentre = x;
      x += maxr;
      return maxr * 2;
    })
  );

  // make scales for position and colour
  var scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0,totalWidth]).range([0, width]);
  var colScale = d3.scale.category10();

  // add a group per series, position the group according to the values and position scale  we calculated above
 var groups = svg.selectAll("g").data(data);
 groups.enter().append("g");
 groups.attr("transform", function(d) {
        return ("translate("+scale(d.xcentre)+",0)");
 });

 // then add circles per series, biggest first as items are sorted
 // colour according to index (the property we inserted previously so we can
 // keep track of their original position in the series)
 var circles = groups.selectAll("circle").data(function(d) { return d.items;}, function(d) { return d.index; });
 circles.enter().append("circle").attr("cy", height/2).attr("cx",0);

 circles
    .attr("r", function(d) { return scale(Math.sqrt (d.value)); })
  .style ("fill", function (d) { return colScale(d.index); });
```

Comment: I've added a series id -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/4/  - so I mean will this help ensure the circles are painted properly

Comment: That essentially what both @mgraham and I did.  We just did it dynamically with a `.forEach`...

Comment: I see - the next step may then be to add labels https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYTn7.png  http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/7/

Comment: Be keen to start putting pointers/labels on it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082179/d3-labelled-multi-series-chart

Comment: Actually, I made an omission in that I made a position scale but then didn't use it... fixed now - http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/22/

Comment: @mgraham http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096552/d3-js-fixed-angles-for-pointers - any suggestions on the labels?

Comment: @Mark http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096552/d3-js-fixed-angles-for-pointers - any suggestions on the labels?

Comment: Hello @mgraham,Mark - I got another issue - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart/43461927#43461927

Comment: Hello @mgraham - have another problem you could maybe help resolve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart/43461927#43461927

Comment: Hello @Mark - have another problem you could maybe help resolve - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43415966/d3-js-chemical-tube-bar-chart/43461927#43461927

Answer (score 1):

mgraham's answer is great!   But since I had already written this out (and then had to go to a meeting) here's how I would code it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  var el = $('.serieschart');
  var w = el.data("width");
  var h = el.data("height");


  var margin = {
    top: 65,
    right: 90,
    bottom: 5,
    left: 150
  };

  var svg = d3.select(el[0]).append("svg")
    .attr("class", "series")
    .attr("width", w + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", h + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  var data = [{
    "name": "Twitter",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Facebook",
    "items": [{
      "value": 300
    }, {
      "value": 200
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Ebay",
    "items": [{
      "value": 1000
    }, {
      "value": 2000
    }]
  }, {
    "name": "Foursquare",
    "items": [{
      "value": 2000
    }, {
      "value": 3000
    }]
  }]


  // sort items array descending by size
  // this will help us draw the bigger one first
  // introduce an index for color assignment
  data.forEach(function(d){
   d.items.forEach(function(d1,i){
      d1.id = i;
    })
    d.items.sort(function(x, y){
      return d3.descending(x.value, y.value);
    });
  });
  
  circleMaker();

  function circleMaker() {

    var colors = d3.scale.category10();
    var counter = 0,
        prevR = 0;

    svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("circle")
      .data(function(d){       
       return d.items;
      })
      .enter()
      .append("circle")
      .attr("cy", 60)
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
        d.r = Math.sqrt(d.value);
        if (i === 0) {
          counter += prevR + d.r;
          prevR = d.r;
        }
        return counter;
      })
      .attr("r", function(d){
        return d.r;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d){
        return colors(d.id);
      });
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  background: #eeeeee;
}
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div id="holder">
  <div class="serieschart" data-role="serieschart" data-width=450 data-height=180></div>
</div>
```

Comment: series id -- jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/4 --- what about ensuring there is a series id -- to ensure the data sets don't get mixed up etc..

Comment: I see - the next step may then be to add labels https://i.stack.imgur.com/nYTn7.png  http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/7/

Comment: Be keen to start putting pointers/labels on it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43082179/d3-labelled-multi-series-chart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43096552/d3-js-fixed-angles-for-pointers - any suggestions on the labels?